# RouteConfig can't find the URL address from controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fetch data using this url *http://localhost:4148/api/ordertypetemplate/list* with the configuration below.
There might be something wrong configuration I did. 
What did I do wrong?

RouteConfig

```
     routes.MapRoute(
                name: "OrderTypeTemplate",
                url: "ordertypetemplate/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "OrderTypeTemplate" }
            );
```

controller

```
       [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/ordertypetemplate/list")]
        public IEnumerable<OrderTypeTemplateIndexModel> GetTemplateList()
        {
            return _orderTypeTemplateService.GetTemplateList();
        }
```

Comment: Would suggest to include the url as "api/ordertypetemplate/{action}"

Comment: @VIJAY I tried that one too but it didn't work. It is all from Apicontroller so I think api is prefix.